# Does mysql 5.0 index null values?

Tags: mysql, null, indexing

I realize that the exact question has been asked before on stack overflow with only a vaguely conclusive answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289001/does-mysql-index-null-values)

So here it is again.

Table A: Has an integer column which is nullable, along with an index.
Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column IS NULL 
LIMIT 10;
```

Will an index be used, or will mysql do a full table scan until it has found 10 entries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think this should be helpful:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

> A search using col_name IS NULL employs indexes if col_name is
>   indexed.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know that for sure in **your specific case** is to run "EXPLAIN SELECT" on your query.

It really depends on the number of NULLs in your table compared with total number of rows; whether table statistics have been updated, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to analyze the query. In general, it depends on the relative percentage of `NULLs` to values. If a majority of the entries in that integer column is NULL, that it will likely skip it.

On the other hand, if only 10% (for example) are `NULL`, it will (or should) use the index.

Comment: Thank you sir. I just needed a review of this. And I would like to add for anyone that comes to this page in the future that your answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to know it.

You can execute this command `show index from tablename` and it will return some analysis results which one is called NULL.

if NULL equals YES, your index contains NULL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html