# MYSQL INDEX for sparse table

Tags: mysql, indexing

Scenario: You want to create a **secondary index** for MYSQL (category_id, for example); but 80% of the time it's zero (we never search for it); and 20% it's meaningful (we will actual search for this).

How could you create the secondary index so that it doesn't index the zero value (which is useless)?

Example table:

```
create table Test (
    id int primary key,
    secondary_id int,
    data text
)
```

The query is:

```
select *
from Test
where secondary_id = some_value
```

Comment: Why don't you set null instead of zero. Null values will not be included in the secondary index.

Comment: Do you have an performance issue if the zeros are indexed?   What is the problem if you just create a secondary index that does include the zeros?

Comment: Yeah, "not a problem".  All the "0"s will be at one end of the index, wasting disk space, but not performance.

Comment: @hiro: I think your problem is that 80% field value is 0 i.e. same so mysql will not use index instead use table scan, to use index may be work if you create composit index on (secondary_id,id).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf An obvious consequence is wasting disk space as Rick James mentioned. I do not have enough data to know if it affects performance.

Comment: @ntalbs The answer to this question seems to indicate that it does index NULL's   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289001/does-mysql-index-null-values     Which would make sense as you can select for NULL or NOT NULL in queries.