# Mysql Innodb indexing on a column with majority null values

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb

I tried to index a date time field in a table with 20 million rows. Majority(99%) of the rows for that column are null. After that, CPU utilization shot up to 100% because of this. I'm not able to find out the exact reason for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does mysql index null values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289001/does-mysql-index-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

As an optimization, InnoDB "delays" the updating of indexes.  Probably what happened is that this delayed operation is happening, causing the CPU to spike.

For further info, search for "InnoDB change buffering".

Comment: I deleted the indexes once CPU spiked up. I need to be sure of the root cause before I create the indexes again. Any pointers for debugging? Any estimate for it's delayed index update to complete?

Comment: 20M rows -- They have to be scanned, a file created and sorted, then written back to disk, etc.  Please show us the command you used and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Minutes / hours.  Depends on lots of things -- size of table, setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, spinning drives vs SSDs, etc

Comment: Algo used:
`CREATE INDEX name-index on table-name(column-name) algorithm=inplace`